# delete records from a table based on data from a different table

Tags: sql, mysql

table1 has column CITY and COUNTRY. table2 has column CITY.

how do i delete from table2 all records that have CITY in common with table1 but also the COUNTRY='Russia' ??

please keep in mind that both tables have about 1 million rows of data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DELETE table2
FROM table2 INNER JOIN table1
   ON table2.CITY = table1.CITY
WHERE table1.COUNTRY = 'Russia'
```

Comment: @Mark Byers has updated his answer to something closer to mine. You want to delete from table2 in your question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [multitable delete syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/delete.html):

```
DELETE table2
FROM table1
JOIN table2
ON table1.city = table2.city
WHERE table1.country = 'RUSSIA'
```

Comment: you and ddc have tables in opposite places, are u sure this is right?

Comment: I've fixed my mistake in the first line. Regarding the rest, it doesn't matter whether you write `table1 JOIN table2` or `table2 JOIN table1`. These give the same result.